# Actionscripts3 read JSON from VPS issue

Tags: php, actionscript-3, air, animate-cc

In Adobe AIR Dektop, I wrote some code to read JSON data from our VPS, I think my AS3 codes are true but I'm not sure about the PHP codes. Adobe Animate console is empty after I run project.

This program have access to other sites and after run i can read data from them, but from our VPS i can't.

AS3:

```
import flash.events.*;
import flash.net.*;
var loader: URLLoader;
var request: URLRequest;
function load(): void {
    request = new URLRequest("212.73.150.148/asphp.php");
    loader = new URLLoader();
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
    loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError);
    loader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onError);
    loader.load(request);
}
function onError(e: Event): void {
    trace(e.target.data + "READING DATA FROM VPS ERROR");     
}
function onComplete(e: Event) {
    trace(e.target.data);        
    var json: Object = JSON.parse(e.target.data);
    trace("json.DATA1 = ", json.DATA1);
    trace("json.DATA2 = ", json.DATA2);
}
load();
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
$arr = array ('DATA1'=>"111",'DATA2'=>"222");
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Comment: Maybe really do a trace in `onError`?

Comment: Yes error!. maybe it is related to permission and security.

Comment: In application settings, "Access local files only" selected and it's disabled.

Comment: Well, what kind of error do you receive? Classify the event, display the message, etc etc.

Comment: I updated code in onError function. i don't know what kind of error is.

Comment: I'm using AIR Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I used wrong URL value "212.73.150.148/asphp.php"  after change to "http://212.73.150.148/asphp.php" it worked.